# PHP y JQuery, mostrar al usuario el sumo de los select seleccionados

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario, en archivo php, donde quiero que sin recargar la pagina, me sume todos los value seleccionados, y me aparezca a la misma vez en un botton submit para que al darle al boton se elimine el formulario y aparezca un listado de checkbox

esta es mi idea principal pero os pido ayuda para mi primera parte, que no sé como podría con javascript y php de formato ( archivo ) hacer que aparezca la suma de los value sin recargar la página, es decir por un evento al seleccionar cada

> selection

y ponerlo en el botton

```
<input type="button"  value="Calcular" />
```

muchs gracias de ante mano, sois de gran ayuda

```
<section>
        <div id="formulario">
            <form method="post" id="formulario">

                <label for="Vaciar SPAM">Vaciar SPAM</label>
                <select id="spam" class="tiempos" name="spam">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="buscarNetflix">Buscar pelis en Netflix </label>
                <select id="netflix" name="netflix">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="tráfico">Tráfico</label>
                <select id="trafico" name="trafico">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="fotoIG">Elegir foto para Instagram </label>
                <select id="fotoIG" name="fotoIG">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="nopTinder">Nopes en Tinder </label>
                <select id="nopTinder" name="nopTinder">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="mirarRopa">Mirar ropa</label>
                <select id="mirarRopa" name="mirarRopa">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="dirijaYT">Dejar que YouTube dirija mi tiempo </label>
                <select id="dirijaYT" name="dirijaYT">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <input type="button"  value="Calcular" />
            </form>
            <input type="hidden" id="ocultoResultado" name="paso">
            <br />
            Tiempo total: <span id="resultado">0</span>
            

        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Primero, creo que deberias modificar el título de la pregunta, ya que es demasiado amplio, luego podrías aclarar si lo que quieres es la suma para enviarla al servidor o solamente para que se muestre al usuario o que es lo que harías con el dato. Saludos.

Comment: vale, lo necesito para que se muestre en la misma pagina sin refrescar al usuario

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que la suma se debe hacer en PHP, ¿hacer la suma directamente en javascript no te valdría? es algo más corto y simple, pero menos seguro.
Entiendo que la duda la tienes en el proceso de mandar los datos al servidor de forma asincrona.

Una de las cosas que puedes utilizar con JavaScript moderno es Fetch.

Si los valores los quieres enviar por POST (algo más seguro que GET), puede servirte el siguiente ejemplo. Por favor, revisa la sintaxis, que no tengo un IDE JS en estos momentos disponible.

```
function getDataFromDOM() {
    const data = new FormData();    
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('#formulario select option:selected').each(function() {
            var parentID=$(this).parent().attr("id");
            var timeValueSelected=$(this).attr("value");
            data.append(parentID, timeValueSelected);
        });
    });
    return data;
}
    
$(document).ready(function(){
    const data=getDataFromDOM();
    fetch('../post.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    })
   .then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
          return response.text()
      } else {
          throw "Error en la llamada Ajax";
      }
   }).then(function(texto) {
        //Tu código de respuesta aquí
        $("#formulario").remove();//El resto de cosas que quieras hacer...
        console.log(texto);
    })
   .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
   });
});
```

Para próximas consultas te recomiendo que realices una pregunta más definidas y cerradas.

Espero que te sirva!
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La parte de los checkbox no la entendi muy bien, creo que deberias explicar mejor lo que quieres hacer, la parte de sumar los valores se puede hacer con JS, te dejo un ejemplo usando `querySelectorAll` para obtener los valores y luego sumarlos con un `for`, quedaría asi:

```js
function calcular(){

var datos = document.querySelectorAll('option:checked');
    var total=0;
    for(var i=0;i<datos.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(datos[i].value))
            total += parseInt(datos[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <div id="formulario">
            <form method="post" id="formulario">
                <label for="Vaciar SPAM">Vaciar SPAM</label>
                <select id="spam" class="tiempos" name="spam">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="buscarNetflix">Buscar pelis en Netflix </label>
                <select id="netflix" name="netflix">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="tráfico">Tráfico</label>
                <select id="trafico" name="trafico">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="fotoIG">Elegir foto para Instagram </label>
                <select id="fotoIG" name="fotoIG">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="nopTinder">Nopes en Tinder </label>
                <select id="nopTinder" name="nopTinder">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="mirarRopa">Mirar ropa</label>
                <select id="mirarRopa" name="mirarRopa">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label for="dirijaYT">Dejar que YouTube dirija mi tiempo </label>
                <select id="dirijaYT" name="dirijaYT">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <input type="button" onclick="calcular()"  value="Calcular" />
            </form>
            <input type="hidden" id="ocultoResultado" name="paso">
            <br />
            Tiempo total: <span id="resultado">0</span>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Si explicas mejor la otra parte, modificare mi respuesta para ayudarte. Saludos.